# how to show result at another form after click button?

Tags: jquery

i have two form.
at form 1 there are:

```
1. one group of radiobutton
    <input id="def1" type="radio" class="defect" name="defect" value="S"/>S
    <input id="def2" type="radio" class="defect" name="defect" value="A" />A
    <input id="def3" type="radio" class="defect" name="defect" value="B" />B
    <input id="def4" type="radio" class="defect" name="defect" value="C" />C

2. <button id="accept" value="accept">accept</button>
   <button id="reject" value="reject">reject</button>
```

at form 2:

```
1. <input type="text" id="class">
2. <input type="text" id="status">
```

for example, if i choose `A` from radiobutton then click `reject`,at form 2 can show result:

```
at id="class" is A and at id="status" is reject
```

Comment: Can you explain better your purpose? It sounds a bit confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selectedDefect;
    $('input[name="defect"]').click(function() {
        selectedDefect = $(this).val();
    });
    $('#accept').click(function() {
        $('#class').val(selectedDefect);
        $('#status').val('accept');
    });
    $('#reject').click(function() {
        $('#class').val(selectedDefect);
        $('#status').val('reject');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@sabbour i think it's wrong to wrap the name with "",

instead of

```
$('input[name="defect"]').click(function() {
   selectedDefect = $(this).val(); 
});
```

should be

```
$('input[name=defect]').click(function() {
   selectedDefect = $(this).val(); 
});
```